# On Size Error doesn't give expected output

Tags: cobol

When I run the below code I get the following output:

```
       Var1: 761758
Actual-Var1: 761.758
Result-Var1: 761.75
```

What I'm expecting is:

```
Result-Var1 is incorrect size!
       Var1: 761758
Actual-Var1: 761.758
Result-Var1: 761.75
```

I'm teaching myself COBOL and I'm using Michael Coughlan's book, Beginning COBOL for Programmers. His minimal example of the `ON SIZE ERROR` phrase is on page 62. It seems straight forward but I can't get the output that I want. Any suggestions? In addition, I'm using Micro Focus Visual COBOL for Ecplise as my IDE.

```
       Identification Division.
       Program-ID. OnSizeErrorDemo.

       Data Division.
       Working-Storage Section.
         01 Var1 Pic 999V999 Value 761.758.
         01 Actual-Var1 Pic 999.999.
         01 Result-Var1 Pic 999.99.

       Procedure Division.
       Begin.
         Move Var1 To Actual-Var1

         Compute Result-Var1 = Var1
           On Size Error Display "Result-Var1 is incorrect size!"
         End-Compute

         Display "       Var1: ", Var1
         Display "Actual-Var1: ", Actual-Var1
         Display "Result-Var1: ", Result-Var1
       Stop Run
```

Comment: I do not have that book, and cannot find online copy. First suggestion is to review the PIC-s and VALUES. Second look at compiler options for Size Errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result appears to be correct. Low-order digits will be truncated unless the `ROUNDED` phrase is used.

The `SIZE ERROR` phrase would take affect if the value of the result is greater than the `PICTURE` clause, in this case `999.99`. Try

```
 Compute Result-Var1 = Var1 + Var1
   On Size Error Display "Result-Var1 is incorrect size!"
 End-Compute
```

to test the `SIZE ERROR` phrase. `Result-Var1` should be unchanged.

Comment: "You didn't mention the output you were expecting." Yes I did, it's at the top of the post.

Comment: So `On Size Error` only kicks in if there's not enough memory space on the left side of the decimal place, is that what I missed?

Comment: @MichaelSwartz - I've removed the incorrect statement.

Comment: @MichaelSwartz - It is actually related to the significant `9`s in the `PICTURE` clause. Consider that `PIC 0.099` will hold values from `0.000` to `0.099`. Any value greater than that will cause a `SIZE ERROR`, even though all `9`s are right of the decimal point. The amount of memory reserved depends on the `USAGE`, `PICTURE` and `SIGN` clauses. See the description of "storage representation" in the "language reference manual" for the compiler.